# Gate Keeper not Accepting Code signed macOs Application

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, apple-developer

- I have created an apple developer account
- Created a Certificate request from Keychain tool,Uploaded it and generated a certificate for `Macos distribution`
- Downloaded the certificate,double clicked and installed it.
- Build the `.app` package and used the codesign tool `codesign --force --sign "Apple Development:Cool Developer(27HS88RR)" "mysupercoolapp.app"`
- Used the following command for verification `codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 "mysupercoolapp.app"` the ouput is `Valid on Disk,Satisfies some requirement`
- Using the `spctl` tool for Gatekeeper verification `spctl -a -t exec --vv "mysupercoolapp.app"` --> Rejected

Is there some magic trick for gatekeeper to accept the app? I'm fed up of this,apple does not have proper documentation on codesigning a macOs app from xcode directly. 
Please advice

Comment: "Apple Development:..." is the wrong certificate; you need a "Developer ID Application:..." certificate. See [Apple's list of developer certificate types](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev80c6204ec). You may also need to submit the app for notarization; see [this developer doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/resolving_common_notarization_issues)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks ... i will check it.